# Resistance tester

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, comparator, test, tester

I would need to create a simple tester with battery supply that compares resistance of specific wire with reference (approximately 4 ohms) and determines if the wanted resistance is in desired range.  I know that can be achieved with an op amp - comparator. The result should be indicated with two LED´s. Green means that wanted resistance is in reference range and red LED indicates just the opposite.

How do I create a simple wire tester that can determine a range of resitance and indicate that?

Comment: You are sure you want to measure a *resistance* of 4Ω, not an *impedance* of 4Ω?

Comment: Simple 2-comparater setup. One for the low limit, other for the high limit of the range. Use voltage deviders to get your reference voltages, and use the same source voltage to test your DUT (this will elliminate any requirement for accurate voltage refernces - only the ratios of resistances are important).

Comment: If only multimeters existed that gave a read out on a numerical display.

Comment: This is a pretty simple assignment. What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

The resistance you intend to measure is quite small. In this case you will want to go with a "four wire measurement": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing

This will give you a voltage output related to the resistance of the wire which you can feed into a circuit to indicate pass/fail, have a look at comparators: http://www.ermicro.com/blog/?p=1578